# how to define new column type in liferay service builder

Tags: liferay-6

I want to define an entity like below:

```xml
<entity name="Book" local-service="true" remote-service="true">
    <column name="bookId" type="long" primary="true" />

    <column name="bookPrice" type="BigDecimal"  />
</entity>
```

my liferay is 6.0.6.

how can it possible to create new type like BigDecimal or other types in liferay service builder?